# Microsoft Access Testing

Tags: testing, networking, loading, ms-access-2003

I have inherited an Access database that has linked SQL tables. I need to test the network traffic that is caused by the execution of the Db. I need to ascertain which parts of the system cause the most Network traffic and therefore are the slowest.

I am not an access guru so ive struggled doing what was suggested, which is : have Task Manager open at the Networking tab.
Then Step in into the app and looking at where there is a significant rise in Network traffic. But this seems rather unreliable and time consuming.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve my goal in Access?

Comment: Not sure that network traffic is a good yardstick for system slowness: in many cases the time the db engine spends in searching your data (and during that time the client is waiting) will be a lot greater than the time spent to transfer the data to a client. If your db-server has a decent query log that might be an easier source of both time spent executing the query AND the quantity data sent back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to analyze the network traffic then you should probably get to know [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) well enough to do a capture that is filtered on the traffic between the client and the SQL server.